# How to find the symlink of a program

Tags: command-line, symbolic-link

When running `firefox`, `/usr/bin/firefox`, I know its symbolically linked to another program but I don't know how to find the symlink of that program. Any help?

Comment: How do you know is a symlink?

Answer (score 12):

The canonical way to resolve symbolic links is to use `readlink`.

To resolve the symbolic link `/usr/bin/firefox`:

```
readlink /usr/bin/firefox
```

Canonicalizing by following all symbolic links in between:

```
readlink -f /usr/bin/firefox
```

For example:

```
$ readlink /usr/bin/firefox
../lib/firefox/firefox.sh

$ readlink -f /usr/bin/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

Note that, for any file that is not a symbolic link, will resolve to itself:

```
$ readlink -f /bin/cat 
/bin/cat
```

Comment: Note: to avoid `../` and make it give full paths, use `-e`

Comment: @BharadwajRaju Did you check my full answer? your point is already solved there..

Comment: Oh, I see. my bad.

Comment: Are there reasons for choosing `-f` vs.`-e` when using `readlink`?

Comment: @edwinksl Yes, both will resolve symlinks recursively but `-f` will work if the last component is missing but `-e` will only work if all components are there..there is also an `-m` option to ignore component existence..check `man readlink`

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

`ls -la /usr/bin/firefox`

This is easy, you can use `ls -la` on any place and can work on multiple files/folder too.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$ file /usr/bin/firefox
```

Which will tell you (among other information) if it is a symlink or not; if yes, to which file.

For example:

```
$ file ~/test.txt
/home/bharadwaj/test.txt: ASCII text

$ file /usr/bin/firefox
/usr/bin/firefox: symbolic link to ../lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```

(Note that `..` means 'parent directory', i.e `/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh`)

To extract just the directory:

```
$ readlink -e /usr/bin/firefox
/usr/lib/firefox/firefox.sh
```